# IP Filtering/Matching by host mask with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address, netmask

I'm wanting to do something similar to this: [Matching an IP to a CIDR mask in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594112/matching-an-ip-to-a-cidr-mask-in-php5)

Except, I want to store a list of disallowed IP/Masks in a MySQL table and check for a match.

Just like the example in the link, something like '10.2.0.0/16' would be a row in the table and then I want to check the IP address of the current user ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and check if it matches or not.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Seams like you know perfectly well what you want and are trying to have your homework done... I really don't see any question there.

Comment: @ShaunO: So what's your question? What part are you having difficulty with? Please edit the question to let us know.

Comment: -1 for "Do my job/homework for me, kthxbai"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options on the tables - you can store the IP as a human-readable string (4 dotted bytes) or in it's native long number that cidr_match uses.  Assuming we've stuck with human readable (to reuse `cidr_match` from the linked page)

```
function testIP($ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    //Returns TRUE - valid, FALSE - denied

    /* Get the data from the database and return it in rows
     * this could be real-time retrieved, or pulled into an array
     * first
     * assumes: deny_ranges(ip VARCHAR(45) not null,mask INT not null default 0)
     * eg: $denyips= get "SELECT ip,mask FROM deny_ranges" from database
     */

    foreach($denyips as $row) {
        if ($row["mask"]==0) {
            //No need to use overhead of CIDR_MATCH
            //Exact match - reject
            if ($row["ip"]==$ip) return false;
        } elseif (cidr_match($ip,$row["ip"]."/".$row["mask"])==true) {
            //In denied range - reject
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Got through all rejected ranges+ips - it's good
    return true;
}
```

(You can find `cird_match` on the other post)

Answer (score 0):

The php.net documentation for `ip2long()` has a good example of working code in the comments: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#86793