# How to get IP address list from CIDR notation in PHP?

Tags: php, cidr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting list IPs from CIDR notation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931721/getting-list-ips-from-cidr-notation-in-php)

Hi there,

I need to generate the list of IP addresses from a CIDR notation.

For example, user has entered 200.41.132.11/28. In return, I need to show the list of IP addresses matching this CIDR notation.

Do you know a PHP function for this or have an algorithm?

Thanks for your help.

Mat.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but try something like this (not tested):

```
function getIPfromCIDR($CIDRn) {
  $a = explode("/", $CIDRn);
  $g = explode(".", $a[0]);
  $b = '';  $res = '';
  foreach ($g as $gv) $b .= str_pad(decbin($gv), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $bm = str_split(str_pad(substr($b, 0, $a[1]), 32, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT), 8);
  foreach($bm as &$bg) $bg = bindec($bg);
  return join('.', $bm); 
  }

$addr = "200.41.132.11/28";
print_r(getIPFromCIDR($addr));
```

Output should be

```
200.41.132.0
```

To get bit mask (network mask) only

```
function bitMask($bits) {
  $res = str_split(str_pad(str_pad('', $bits, '1'), 32, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT), 8);
  foreach($res as &$bg) $bg = bindec($bg); 
  return join('.', $res); 
  }

echo bitMask(28);
```

Output

```
255.255.255.240
```

**Note: It works for IPv4 only!**