# php cidr prefix to netmask

Tags: php, ipv4, cidr

I'm looking to convert a cidr prefix (e.g. /28) to a netmask (e.g. 255.255.255.240) and have not located a function for this, does one exist in php? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: It is primitive math. Can be easily implemented in few minutes.

Comment: Btw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931721/getting-list-ips-from-cidr-notation-in-php

Comment: nvm, got it: Got it!

    $cidr_mask = 24;
    
    $bin = ''; 
    for($i=1;$i<=32;$i++) { 
       $bin .= $cidr_mask >= $i ? '1' : '0';
    }
    $netmask = bindec($bin); 
    echo long2ip($netmask);

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a [class](https://gist.github.com/jonavon/2028872) that contains a method that does this.

```
function CIDRtoMask($int) {
    return long2ip(-1 << (32 - (int)$int));
}
```

I posted the entire class as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jonavon/2028872).

Answer (score 6):

***Example #1:***

### function cidr2NetmaskAddr()

```
  function cidr2NetmaskAddr ($cidr) {

    $ta = substr ($cidr, strpos ($cidr, '/') + 1) * 1;
    $netmask = str_split (str_pad (str_pad ('', $ta, '1'), 32, '0'), 8);

    foreach ($netmask as &$element)
      $element = bindec ($element);

    return join ('.', $netmask);

  }
```

**Usage**

```
  echo cidr2NetmaskAddr ('194.234.213.0/28');
```

**Output**

> 255.255.255.240

---

***Example #2:***

### function createNetmaskAddr()

```
  function createNetmaskAddr ($bitcount) {

    $netmask = str_split (str_pad (str_pad ('', $bitcount, '1'), 32, '0'), 8);

    foreach ($netmask as &$element)
      $element = bindec ($element);

    return join ('.', $netmask);

  }
```

**Usage**

```
  echo createNetmaskAddr (28);
```

**Output**

> 255.255.255.240