# How to calculate IP address range?

Tags: php, ip

I want to calculate IP ranges for a specific IP and Subnet using `PHP`, I mean that I want to calculate Host address range, for example:

```
IP: 91.99.98.243
Subnet: 255.255.255.240
```

Then:

```
Host Address Range: 91.99.98.241 - 91.99.98.254
```

How can I calculate this range using [ip2long()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)?

Comment: No, it is not my answer. for my case it calculate range as: 91.99.98.243 - 91.99.99.2 and it is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the address range only, you can use [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) on the `long` addresses:

```
$ip     = ip2long('91.99.98.243');
$mask   = ip2long('255.255.255.240');
echo 'Host Address Range: ', long2ip($ip & $mask), ' - ', long2ip($ip | ~$mask);
```

If you want to loop on each address, see [calculate IP range using PHP and CIDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961557/calculate-ip-range-using-php-and-cidr) as Joran Den Houting mentioned.

Comment: You need to exclude last address from array (since it will be network address according to IP protocol)