# php is converting base 16 to base 2 incorrectly

Tags: php, encoding, hash, radix, hmac

Why am I getting this output from my function?

```
echo $var = hash_hmac('ripemd160', 'http://www.weburlhere.org', 0, 0);
echo "\r\n";
echo $converted = base_convert($var, 16, 2);
echo "\r\n";
```

Outputs:

```
407a9d8868a678e12d9fc0264f9ae11e8761b557
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Whereas `base_convert($var, 16, 10)` outputs

`1421821959848150668406846884086820088622688484226` correctly.

Also, as a side-question (bonus points for this!) I'm assuming ripemd160 gives me a unique identifier for each input preimage. I'm attempting to make a url-shortening service that shortens a URL from any length to its hash digest (I'm assuming converting the binary to base64 with `base64_encode($converted)` will shorten the URL even more). Is this correct, and is this a good idea?

Comment: Why you are using `hash_hmac`. is it necessary

Comment: Deriving a short and unique value (such as a hash) from a URL will not work very well. It would be easier to just keep a counter somewhere, and base-36 (to avoid upper- and lowercase collisions) hash it to make it as short as possible. I have no idea how binary numbers come into it, however...

Comment: I thought base64 encoding would provide a shorter URL so I had to convert the hex to binary first since `base64_encode` requires binary input data (or so I thought).

Comment: @bvpx, Sverri M. Olsen's idea was to have auto incremental number (ID in the database), and convert the ID into higher base (can be base64) to provide a shorter link instead of hashing the URL and use it as ID.

Comment: The use of the hash has a purpose in my application that is a bit off topic from this discussion and wouldn't fit within the confines of a comment box anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP document on [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) said

> base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties
> related to the internal "double" or "float" type used. Please see the
> Floating point numbers section in the manual for more specific
> information and limitations.

So, you cannot rely on this function to convert a large numbers. However, it is very easy manually write a function to convert from base 16 to base 2.

```
function hex2bin($hex) {
    $table = array('0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', 
                   '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111',
                   '1000', '1001', 'a' => '1010', 'b' => '1011', 
                   'c' => '1100', 'd' => '1101', 'e' => '1110', 
                   'f' => '1111');
    $bin = '';
    
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i++) {
        $bin .= $table[strtolower(substr($hex, $i, 1))];
    }
    
    return $bin;
}
echo hex2bin('407a9d8868a678e12d9fc0264f9ae11e8761b557');
```

> I'm assuming converting the binary to base64 with
> base64_encode($converted) will shorten the URL even more). Is this
> correct, and is this a good idea

Yes, it is shorter. It is 32 times shorter than binary, and 4 times shorter than base-16. However, ripemd160 does not guarantee to give an unique identifier for every link. There are still some collisions (which I don't even know how rare it will be).

Comment: Note: The [GMP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) may be helpful here, especially the [gmp_strval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php) function. Converting hex to binary is pretty easy, though, and could be done in a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, but needs to select another name, because `Cannot redeclare hex2bin()`

Comment: @a55, you are right. I made the change.

Comment: So please change `a =>` to `'a' =>` , thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the PHP manual, the [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) is limited to `double` or `float` 32-bit precision. You can use `gmp` library to deal with numbers of arbitrary length.

A [sample code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#51077) also from the PHP manual page:

```
/* use gmp library to convert base. gmp will convert numbers > 32bit
 * @author lindsay at bitleap dot com
 * @link you can execute this code at http://ideone.com/FT29qo
 */
function gmp_convert($num, $base_a, $base_b)
{
    return gmp_strval ( gmp_init($num, $base_a), $base_b );
}
```

Comment: `Call to undefined function gmp_strval()` Then `apt install php-gmp`