# Finding if an IPv6 address is part of a subnet or not

Tags: c++, ipv6

I have two IPv6 addresses in string format

1) ipv6addr1 is a global network.

2) ipv6addr2 is the current address

I need to find if ipv6addr2 is within the same subnet range of ipv6addr1.

I know I can convert addresses to bytes and then shift bits by prefix and compare but IPv6 addresses are 128 Bits and I cant think of breaking into two longs and then doing it.

Comment: Hint : 128 bits = 16 bytes ~= 4 `ints` each of 4 bytes..so address fits in array of 4 `ints`

Comment: I am doing this If you need to compare masked addresses then you will have to do a little more work. inet_pton will not parse prefix lengths ("/something") for you so you will have to:

Find the slash
Pass the part before the slash to inet_pton
Parse the integer after the slash with plain ol' atoi
Manually zero out 128 minus that number of bits at the end of the binary form of the address

Comment: But How do I Zero out the "128 -prefix" bits in the in6_addr ?

Comment: This question has already been answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951061

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching IPv6 address to a CIDR subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951061/matching-ipv6-address-to-a-cidr-subnet)