# How to calculate end IP in the range, based on start IP and network mask length

Tags: php, ip-address

I have a starting IPv4 IP address `5.39.28.128` (or `::ffff:5.39.28.128`) and I have the IPv6 network mask length `122`, how can I calculate the last IP in the range?

I believe I need to convert the start IP to binary, which I'm doing like below, I don't know where to go from there to get the end IP.

```
$ipNumber = ip2long('5.39.28.128');
$ipBinary = decbin($ipNumber);

echo $ipBinary; // 101001001110001110010000000
```

The reason is I'm importing the MaxMind GeoIP database in CSV format into a MySQL database (so MySQL functions can be used if needed). MaxMind no longer provide the end IP, in favour of providing the start IP and the IPv6 network mask length instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate broadcast address from ip and subnet mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777617/calculate-broadcast-address-from-ip-and-subnet-mask)

Comment: @TrippKinetics not a duplicate of that. I'm asking about PHP not C and I don't have the full netmask, only the length.

Comment: #1, there is no difference in the logic even if the language is different.  #2, the netmask and the length are equivalent. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Comment: @TrippKinetics What you are correct about that, and your link is valuable, this question is not a duplicate.  Duplicate questions are to be truly duplicates, and the language difference makes it not a duplicate.

Comment: Do you want to do this in php or MySQL?  If you are not interested in MySQL, then please remove the tag from the question.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.soucy.org/project/inet6/ ? It includes a PHP function `inet_to_range()` which outputs the first and last IPv6 address for a range, given an address and a CIDR prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Here you are. I've copied the `inet_to_bits` function from [this response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951061/matching-ipv6-address-to-a-cidr-subnet).

```php
<?php

function inet_to_bits($inet) {
   $inet = inet_pton($inet);
   $unpacked = unpack('A16', $inet);
   $unpacked = str_split($unpacked[1]);
   $binaryip = '';
   foreach ($unpacked as $char) {
             $binaryip .= str_pad(decbin(ord($char)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   }
   return $binaryip;
}

function bits_to_inet($bits) {
    $inet = "";
    for($pos=0; $pos<128; $pos+=8) {
        $inet .= chr(bindec(substr($bits, $pos, 8)));
    }
    return inet_ntop($inet);
}

$ip = "::ffff:5.39.28.128";
$netmask = 122;

// Convert ip to binary representation
$bin = inet_to_bits($ip);

// Generate network address: Length of netmask bits from $bin, padded to the right
// with 0s for network address and 1s for broadcast
$network = str_pad(substr($bin, 0, $netmask), 128, '1', STR_PAD_RIGHT);

// Convert back to ip
print bits_to_inet($network);
```

Output:

```
::ffff:5.39.28.191
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer. Would this code support real IPv6 addresses as well as the IPv4 in the IPv6 style?

Comment: Yes, no changes required.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is quite simple:

```
// Your input data
$networkstart = '5.39.28.128';
$networkmask = 122;

// First find the length of the block: IPv6 uses 128 bits for the mask
$networksize = pow(2, 128 - $networkmask);

// Reduce network size by one as we really need last IP address in the range,
// not first one of subsequent range
$networklastip = long2ip(ip2long($networkstart) + $networksize - 1);
```

$networklastip will have last IP address in the range.

Now this is good solution ONLY for IPv4 addresses in IPv6 address space. Otherwise you need to use IPv6 to/from 128 bit integer functions instead of ip2long/long2ip. However for use by MaxMind data code above is sufficient as I have not seen any actual IPv6 data from them yet.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer. Is it a simple change to do the same thing for IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Yes, basically you dealing with long integers. In IPv4 is is 32 bit long, in IPv6 it is 128 bit long. Math around prefixes exactly the same: two in power of (max prefix length - given prefix length) gives you block size. Add block size to beginning address and you get beginning address of next block. Minus one and you get last address of the block.

Comment: I see. So it's a case of swapping the ip2long and long2ip for the equivalent IPv6 version? Are you aware of those functions? I couldn't find anything on php.net.

Comment: There are no equivalent IPv6 version, because an IPv6 address is 16 byte long and php does only supports up to 8 bytes natively. You'll have to work with a string representation (like I do in my answer) or a large integer extension like [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: @Philip My only issue with your solution is inefficiency. Loading MaxMind data calls for good amount of transformations and it will be awfully slow. However I support your thoughts about BC Math or GMP - both may do well. Another option is to break IPv6 into four double quads and convert them into integer. Then apply mask the same way as I have offered. Nothing complex but requires some coding. Performance wise I guess it should be decent.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of weird everyone just ignored the suggested duplicate that was posted 2 minutes after the question was asked. [The upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777631/1255289) there provides a very simple solution in C:

```c
broadcast = ip | (~ subnet);
```

Obviously we can't do that with the human-readable strings, so takes a bit of math to get to the same place:

```php
$network = '::ffff:5.39.28.128/122';
[$address, $bits] = explode('/', $network);
$hex_length = str_contains($address, ':') ? 32 : 8;
$address = inet_pton($address);
$mask = str_repeat('f', $bits / 4) . match($bits % 4) {
    0 => '',
    1 => '8',
    2 => 'c',
    3 => 'e',
};
$mask = pack('H*', str_pad($mask, $hex_length, '0'));

$first_in_net = inet_ntop($address & $mask);
$last_in_net = inet_ntop($address | ~$mask);

echo "Network range is $first_in_net – $last_in_net";
```

Output:

```
Network range is ::ffff:5.39.28.128 – ::ffff:5.39.28.191
```

---

**Explanatory notes**:

Converting an IP to a number is simple enough with a single call to `inet_pton()`. But the mask stuff is a bit more involved when working with IPv6. A 122-bit mask means a binary number with 122 ones and 6 zeros. PHP can't work with numbers that large so we have to convert that binary string into hex digits.

Each 4 binary digits becomes a single hex digit, and we start by converting all the opening `1111` to `f`. Complications arise at the boundary between ones and zeros, which is what the `match` statement handles (`1000` to `8`, `1100` to `c`, and `1110` to `e`.) Then we use `str_pad` to fill in the remaining zeros. (The process is exactly the same with IPv4, but the mask is only 8 hex digits instead of 32.)

Our 122-bit mask becomes `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc0` which is then packed into a number, to match the output of `inet_pton`. Once we have both elements as numbers, we get to do the simple bit math to calculate the range.