# Block and/or Redirect Large List of IPs using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, redirect, ip-address

I have an external list of IPs I would like to block (or, better yet, redirect) on my website.  I first was taking the `.htaccess` approach but then realized that it might be easier to do this with PHP.  But now I'm not sure... Seems like PHP and MySQL together is the best option.

I have a table in MySQL that holds the CIDR blocks.  I've been struggling with trying to compare the user's IP to the table.

What's the best method?

I was thinking of checking the blocked IP in some way, something like this (PHP and psuedocode):

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

loop through returned rows {
    if ($user_ip in returned row from MySQL table) {
        forward to another domain
    }

    else // do something else...
}
```

But I'm dealing with groups of IPs; not single IPs. I've been working with some CIDR scripts and ip2long to disassemble and parse the groups.  But this has proven difficult.

Based on a suggestion from the comments, if I stored the IPs in the database, I could compare directly.  But the entire block I'm dealing with is huge and I'm not sure about doing it this way.  I'd be dealing with millions of IPs on the comparison...

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd import those IP blocks into a database - I should think it'll be faster than reading that array into memory every time. Then, you'll need to do some bitwise ops for each one to determine whether an IP fits into each block. I should think you wouldn't want to hold IPs individually - there's probably too many to use the equality operator efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. I've read here and elsewhere that MySQL is a better approach. I'm in the process of working up the script.

Comment: Store them in the database as strings, and make sure the column is indexed, and run a simple `where ip = ?` query. Don't get into any "bitwise" operator stuff, and don't listen to somebody telling you that the "equality operator" is inefficient. That's just wrong.

Comment: Thanks meager.  In your comment, when you say 'store them', are you referring to the individual IPs or the CIDR block?  If I store the blocks (~4000 entries) versus IPs (way more - millions), this surely will affect the processing time.  Seems I will have to use the CIDR class to search if the IP is inside the returned block, if storing blocks...

Comment: Have you considered using CloudFlare for your website? It's free and it allows you to block group IPs without the fuss of writing all the code.

You also do not waste resources on your machine to check whether or not to block the IP, everything is done by CloudFlare's machines.

Comment: I have not - but I will look into that right now.  My main goal is to not just block, but actually redirect.  We have a business agreement with a reseller that needs the users to go there instead...  But thanks again - looking at CloudFlare now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ge this sorted out finally.  Here is what I did...

First, I created a script that injected my huge list of IP CIDR blocks into MySQL.

Then, I wrote a script that first queried the database, fetched the IP blocks, 
collected them into an array, and then used functions found herein ( [Find whether a given IP exists in CIDR or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243594/find-whether-a-given-ip-exists-in-cidr-or-not) ) to compare the user's IP to the CIDR blocks from the database.

```
// initialize array
$cidr_block = array();

// query mysql database for all id and ip_cidr values
$query = "SELECT id, ip_cidr FROM ip_blocks";

// use mysqli class to query database
if ($result = $mysqli -> query($query)) {

    // build array for testing with  IP_vs_CIDR class
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $cidr_block[] = $row['ip_cidr'];
    }

    // run IP_vs_CIDR on user ip address and cidr block array from database
    $cidr_result = $ip_vs_cidr -> test_user_ip($user_ip, $cidr_block);

    // test ip against the array values and send elswhere if bad
    if ($cidr_result) {
        header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    }

    // free up result set
    $result -> close();
}
```

Then, I redirected based on this result.  Seems to be working nicely, as several tests with fixed IPs for user IP (eg, `$user_ip = '75.150.41.15')` tested correctly and redirected as expected.  I tested IPs from the black list and not, to cover both bases.

Thanks to those for your comments - they were helpful.