# Add range of IPs in the list of blocked IPs

Tags: php, ip

I have this code which block a certain IP, my problem is I need to block a range of IPs using this format 206.190.155.0/150. I tried it but didn't work. I search for same problem but the format is different, How can I fix it using this format?

Thanks

```
<?php 

$restrictedIPs = array(

'206.190.155.139'

); // array of ips which you want to block
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $restrictedIPs) || in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $restrictedIPs)) {
    echo "<script>
        window.location = 'access-denied.php';
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Is the bit after the slash a subnet mask? In that case you can match them like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594112/matching-an-ip-to-a-cidr-mask-in-php-5

Comment: `echo "Order Allow,Deny\nDeny from 206.190.155.0/24\nAllow from all" > .htaccess`

Comment: yes sir.. @LawrenceCherone how to do that..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/594134/4248328

Comment: thats the one I found that has different format..

Comment: or `iptables -A INPUT -s 206.190.155.0/24 -j DROP`

Comment: or `ufw deny from 206.190.155.0/24` ;p doing it in PHP is not the best way.

Comment: Actually not even in PHP you're using javascript, which won't work to protect from most bots or hackers worth their salt.